# Remap data structure to list of objects from totals

Tags: javascript, arrays

My data is currently:

```
var data = [
  {"date":"01/2020", "x":1, "y":3, "z":4},
  {"date":"02/2020", "x":2, "y":4, "z":6},
  ...
];
```

My desired output is:

```
var data2 = [
  {date:"01/2020", type:"x"},
  {date:"01/2020", type:"y"},
  {date:"01/2020", type:"y"},
  {date:"01/2020", type:"y"},
  {date:"01/2020", type:"z"},
  {date:"01/2020", type:"z"},
  {date:"01/2020", type:"z"},
  {date:"01/2020", type:"z"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"x"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"x"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"y"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"y"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"y"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"y"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"z"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"z"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"z"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"z"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"z"},
  {date:"02/2020", type:"z"},
  ...
];
```

Essentially I'm aiming to unpack the totals in data and configure them into an object format such that the number of objects equals the number of totals. For instance if `y=3` in January then we have three occurrences of `{date:"01/2020", type:"y"}` in `data2`.

I'm not quite sure how to achieve that. I only was able to expand one measily type, in a crude / unscalable way:

```
var data2 = d3.range(3).map(()=>({"type":"y"}));
```

### Question

How can I frame the logic for populating my new array with objects based on totals from the original array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on your `data` array, processing each object and pushing the `date` and each of the other `key` values as an object into your output array, where you push each object the number of times specified by the value associated with the key:

```js
var data = [
  {"date":"01/2020", "x":1, "y":3, "z":4},
  {"date":"02/2020", "x":2, "y":4, "z":6}
];
var data2 = data.reduce((c, { date, ...rest }) => {
  Object.entries(rest).map(([type, v]) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < v; i++) {
      c.push({ date, type });
    }
  });
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(data2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to iterate your data array. For each object in the data array, you can take the entries of the object excluding the `date` property (this object is stored in `r`, and is obtained via [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring)), and map through those to return a new array of the length of each value. Using this new array, you can fill it with `{date, type}` objects. We're using `.flatMap()` here as it allows us to flatten/concatenate the returned results into one resulting array:

```js
const data = [{"date":"01/2020", "x":1, "y":3, "z":4}, {"date":"02/2020", "x":2, "y":4, "z":6},];

const data2 = data.flatMap(({date, ...r}) => Object.entries(r).flatMap(
  ([type, length]) => Array.from({length}, _ => ({date, type}))
));

console.log(data2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Comment: This is a great use of `flatMap` for the inner loop. I was debating using `Array.from` to replace the `for` loop but I still find `for` to be more obvious.

Comment: @Nick thanks, I agree, I usually like to use `for` when building new arrays of a certain length, but I wanted to take a more "functional" approach for this answer I guess + I wanted to show an alternative way from your's and sabbir's answers :)

Comment: Absolutely - the more alternatives the better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```js
var data = [

{"date":"01/2020", "x":1, "y":3, "z":4},
{"date":"02/2020", "x":2, "y":4, "z":6},
];
  

res = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  Object.keys(curr).forEach(key => {
    if(key !== 'date') {
      for(let i = 0; i<curr[key]; i++) {
        prev.push({ date: curr.date, type: key});
      }
    }
  });
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(res)
```